# С сортировкой нарушается вывод символов в консоль

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, консоль, char

Программа принимает любое предложение с клавиатуры, и считает одинаковые символы. Выводится в консоль отсортированным, от большего к меньшему.

Например : АББСС -> 1А 2Б 2С

```
public class CalcuChar {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {

            System.out.print("Слово или фраза: ");
            String string = scan.nextLine();

            if (string.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Вы ничего не ввели!");
                break;
            }

            int[] counters = new int [6600];

            for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
                counters[(int) c]++;
            }

            boolean sortirovka = true;
            while (sortirovka) {
                sortirovka = false;
                for (int i = 1; i < counters.length; i++) {
                        if (counters[i] > counters[i-1]) {
                            swap(counters, i, i- 1);
                            sortirovka = true;
                        }
                }
            }


            System.out.println("Результат:");
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
            for (int i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
                if (counters[i] > 0)
                    System.out.println((char) i+ "   " + counters[i]);
            }

            }

        }

    static void swap(int[] array, int pos1, int pos2) {
        int tmp = array[pos1];
        array[pos1] = array[pos2];
        array[pos2] = tmp;
    }

}
```

Comment: ну так вы 1 символ перекинули и вышли с цикла

Comment: Как сделать чтобы символы не затронуть и сохранить вывод с сортировкой?

Comment: @KindMax А нужен ли вывод номера символа в результате? и  если да, то какой он должен быть? Текущий или тот который занимал в строке? Если текущий, то это 0, 1, 2, ..., N

Comment: @mesfex Символы должны быть только из введенной строки, пока не догоняю как вывести. Сам символ в выводе и количество его повторений

Comment: У вас условие разнится с решением. Написано сделать сортировку, вы всё перегоняете в массив интов,  затем опять делаете каст в char, затем совершенно непонятный boolean sortirovka его вообще надо снести. Сравнение делается задом наперед.

Comment: А поскольку цикл не вложенный, то надо сбрасывать счетчик i

Comment: Такая задача стандартно решается с использованием хэш-таблицы для хранения частоты символов, содержимое которой затем выводится в отсортированном порядке при помощи стандартного алгоритма быстрой сортировки.

Comment: Используйте HashMap. Ключ это символ, а значение это количество повторений. Делается проверка если есть совпадение с ключом значит добавить +1 к значению, если нет, то добавить новую пару к Map. Человек выше сказал , про быструю сортировку. Ее описание есть в книге Шилдт Руководство для начинающих в начале учебника, там же есть и описание пузырьковой. Так же есть уже готовые методы сортировки, погуглите, я имею ввиду библеотеку java.util

Comment: @ДимаЕрохин спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: @KindMax Если помог , тогда плюсаните комментарий , чтоб баллов накинуть, а то еще один минус и я уже не смогу комменты оставлять

Comment: @ДимаЕрохин не могу наверное оценить из-за рейтинга

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитал и сделал так:

```
Map<Character,Integer> amountChar = new HashMap<>();

        for (char c : string.toCharArray()){
            if(amountChar.keySet().contains(c)){
                amountChar.put(c, amountChar.get(c) + 1);
            } else {
                amountChar.put(c,1);
            }
        }
```

А сортировку уже сделал через `.entrySet().stream()`